# NetBeans 8.1 not starting up on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, netbeans

When starting  **netbeans** from the terminal, the following error is received.

```
rishabh@rishabh-HP-Notebook:~$ netbeans
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory (file:/opt/netbeans/platform/lib/boot.jar) to field java.net.URL.handler
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when attempting to use Netbeans 8.1 with Java 9. If `java -version` says 1.9 you can downgrade to 1.8 something like this:

```
# Install Java 8 if you don't already have it.
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk

# Switch to Java 8
sudo update-alternatives --config java

# Attempt to run Netbeans again.
netbeans
```